# How to change the main view from the "Content" view

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an application that look like this [image: My application]

The whole window is defined in the `MainWindow.xaml`, the green part is the content control

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
   Grid.Column="1"
   Margin="5"
   Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
```

The `MainViewModel` looks like this:

```
    public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DetailsViewCommand { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel HomeVm { get; set; }
    public DetailsViewModel DetailsVm { get; set; }
    private object _currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set 
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();    
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        HomeVm = new HomeViewModel();
        DetailsVm = new DetailsViewModel();
        CurrentView = HomeVm;

        HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = HomeVm;
        });
    }
```

Current and default content of the `MainView` is the `HomeView`, I already implemented the event trigger on pressing the item in the list in the `HomeView`. I want to know, what should I write in the `HomeView` method (which is triggering on the click on the item) in order to change the `MainView` content part to another View (`DetailsView` in my case). Code in my `HomeViewModel`:

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            //something here to change the currentView of the MainViewModel
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Got an answer from the guy from discord server.https://discord.gg/AvnpSMDY

You could pass the MainViewModel into the constructor of another view model and assign it to a private readonly field like _mainViewModel. This way you can change the current view either by changing the CurrentView property:

```
_mainViewModel.CurrentView = _mainViewModel.DetailsVm;
```

or executing commands:

```
_mainViewModel.DetailsViewCommand.Execute(null);
```